# Failing to parse xml file with lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to parse an xml file which has &includes; in it but it is failing

File starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE gdml [
        <!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materialsOptical.xml"> 
        <!ENTITY solids SYSTEM "solids.xml"> 
        <!ENTITY matrices SYSTEM "matrices.xml">
]>


<gdml xmlns:gdml="http://cern.ch/2001/Schemas/GDML"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema/gdml.xsd">


<define>
<constant name="PI" value="1.*pi"/>
&matrices;
```

And code being used is

```
from lxml import etree
    #root = etree.fromstring(currentString)
    parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=True)
    root = etree.parse(filename, parser=parser)
```

But I get an error

```
 File "/usr/share/freecad/Mod/GDML/importGDML.py", line 702, in processGDML
    root = etree.parse(filename, parser=parser)
   File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1839, in     lxml.etree._parseDocument
   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1865, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1162, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 600, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 710, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 639, in  lxml.etree._raiseParseError
<class 'lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError'>: Failure to process entity matrices, line 14, column 11 (detector.gdml, line 14)
```

Comment: The entity `matrices` isn't declared in your XML file; is it declared somewhere else? It has to be declared somewhere for your XML to be well-formed. Also, you mention `&includes;` but I'm not sure what that means or where that's coming from.

Comment: I thought that having resolve_entries=True mean't that when the parser came across something like &matrices; it would go fetch the file matrices.gdml and include it. Am  I getting it mixed with something else.

Comment: I just corrected my question with the start of the file. 

Having the Entity statement for matrices.gdml should to my understanding mean it will include the file when parsing

Answer (score 0):

Okay I had download the matrices file as matrices.gdml where as the parent file referred to it as matrices.xml.

Works now